# Symfony 2 dependency injection

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm learning symfony 2 dependency injection system. I'm trying to inject Response object in a controller.

ServiceController.php

```
namespace LD\LearnBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Response $response)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the content of services.yml file (please note that it's included in app/config/config.yml

```
services:
  ld_response:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
  ld_bla:
    class: LD\LearnBundle\ServiceController 
    arguments: ["@ld_response"]
```

When I try to access ServiceController I get

```
Class LD\LearnBundle\Controller\Response does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Some clue on the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) to create a controller as service (if it's the aim).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things wrong here:

1: "Class LD\LearnBundle\Controller\Response does not exist"

The class doesn't exist. You used `Response` without importing the namespace, so the error message is quite explicit here.

2: You shouldn't inject the response. It doesn't make any sense at all. The response is not a service, it's a value that should be passed down through method parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fix:

```
namespace LD\LearnBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; // was missing

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new Response(); // The Controller is responsible of creating the Response.
    }
}
```

Generally, `Class <current-namespace>\class does not exist` errors hint to a missing `use` statement.

May I add that:

- you shouldn't declare your services in the `app/config/config.yml` file (create a specific `services.yml` file. Even better: create it in a bundle)
- you shouldn't inject the Response object: it is the responsibility of the controller to create it